# couldn't create named routes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I defined needed routes in Material App and everything works fine, bit I have to add another button which should lead to authorisation page and now I am getting this error:

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/changeUsers", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate 
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
```

My code look like this:

```
 return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const AuthorizationPage(),
        '/adminLogin': (context) => const AuthInsertLogging(),
        '/mainPageUsers': (context) => const TabBarBottomUsers(),
        '/mainPageAdmin': (context) => const TabBarBottom(),
        "/logout": (_) => new AuthorizationPage(),
        '/changeUsers': (_) => AuthorizationPage(),
      },
    );
  }
```

This is the button I tried to make route:

```
 child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/changeUsers');
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Change User',
                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          letterSpacing: 2),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use the `AuthorizationPage` for `'/' home, '/logout' and '/changeUsers' routes`. There is **a rule for routes property in Flutter documentation**. See details [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/routes.html)

> If `home` is specified, then it implies an entry in this table for the
> Navigator.defaultRouteName route ( here '/' ), and it is an error to
> redundantly provide such a route in the routes table.

The rule says there must be only one `home` route ( here `'/' route` ) is specified. Here there are three routes pointing to same page.

So, just `remove '/logout' and '/changeUers' routes` and write onPressed function as follows.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
```